# Azure Web app service becomes unavailable for a few hours

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-appservice

My azure web app service suddenly becomes unavailable for a few hours.
The app hosts .net core 3.1 web API.
All the requests are pending for a few minutes and then fail. Restarting the app doesn't help. Stopping and starting again too.
Applications insights don't show those failed requests.
Please help, the app serves a lot of users and requests!

[image: Response Time]

I have run Availability and Performance diagnostics at the time of the crash:

[image]

Everything looks just fine except the failed requests.

Comment: Have you tried running the availability and performance diagnostics under diagnose and solve problems to understand why the web app become unavailable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics

Comment: No. Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier , you can debug why the web app went unavailable  by running the availability & performance under [Diagnose and solve problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) in the portal.

You can also refer this [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) to troubleshoot  Troubleshoot HTTP errors of "502 bad gateway" and "503 service unavailable" in Azure App Service

if you are still not able to find any insights , why the webapp went unavailable you can open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) or please create a technical support ticker by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.